# get list of users of fans on my facebook page GRAPH API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I get list of users of fans on my facebook page

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible to get a list of fans for your Facebook page. It is not clear whether this is by design or is a bug.

This [Facebook bug report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12880) suggests that this feature stopped working during October 2010 and is still an outstanding issue.

I hope that it is fixed soon!