# Facebook Graph - Get a list with the names (fans) which follow my own fanpage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there a way to get a list with the names (fans) which follow my own fanpage?

I searched for an answer and the only result that I got is from 2011 ([get list of users of fans on my facebook page GRAPH API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329624/get-list-of-users-of-fans-on-my-facebook-page-graph-api)), which says that it's currently not possible.

I have some experience in code. But my boss wants to get a solution from my side. So I ask you.

Comment: Hasn’t changed. Plus, you could hardly do anything with that information anyway (you are f.e. of course not allowed to contact someone, just because they liked your page.) If demographic info about the fan base is desired, then look into page insights.

Comment: closed, since the answer in that other thread is still correct and will most likely always be.